# Android Emulator (version 12, android studio Chipmunk) randomly get stuck at "waiting for debugger" when debugging

Tags: android, android-studio

I know there are similar questions on this topic. I have tried them all but nothing seems to work permanently. It seems it doesn't follow any pattern. sometimes for a long time it works just fine and sometimes out of a blue it just stuck and I couldn't make it work no matter what I try. It's really frustrating for me because I need my emulator to test different flavors simultaneously.
So please any one have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using windows and you have selected any **RTL languages** in the **regional setting** in windows setting, just change back to english (or any non-RTL language) as you open android studio (or while compiling gradle if you are not using offline mode). It is a weird bug that I thing have something to do with parsing.